# Fiber of a vector bundle at a point on a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

So I'm confused here, and I can't find any satisfactory definitions online for this... So in this text that I am going through, it says the following:

> For a vector bundle V on a smooth curve C and a subspace $K \subset V_p$, where $V_p$ is the fiber of V at a point $p \in C$, ....

I have dealt with fibers of morphisms... But how can you have a fiber of a single object at a point?... Without a morphism... I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough... I'll give an example.

> If X and Y are topological spaces and $p: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map, we say that $p^{-1}(y)$ is the **fiber** of p over y...

And I definitely get this definition... But the case above is dealing with a morphism between objects, and in the set-up with the vector bundle, it's literally just the fiber of a vector bundle at a point on a curve...

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: A vector bundle $V$ on $C$ is given by a morphism $V \to C$.

Comment: @RghtHndSd ah yeah, thank you very much!

Comment: @RghtHndSd So am I interpreting this correctly? Say that you have a morphism $f: V \rightarrow C$... Then $f^{-1}(p)$ would be the fiber of f over our point $p \in C$? I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In algebraic geometry, you need to also give that space the structure of a scheme. This is done through the fiber product, but don't worry about that yet if you're not familiar with schemes.

Comment: @RghtHndSd ah cool, thank you... I'll learn about the fiber product now :)

Comment: @RghtHndSd So intuitively, say you have a morphism $f: V \rightarrow C$. Then $V_p = f^{-1}(p)$ is the fiber for V at a point $p \in C$. This is just a morphism $f^{-1}: C \rightarrow V$ with $p \mapsto f^{-1}(p)$... So is it like this?: you take a point on a curve and the fiber of the vector bundle at the point on the curve is just the structure/behavior of that vector bundle locally at that given point?

Comment: You seem to be forming the right intuition but it lacks rigor. This is okay, but means I can't answer "yes" or "no". However, a section $C \to V$ need not exist.